# How can i determine my real internet speed[bandwidth]

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, bandwidth

In real time , How can i determine my real internet speed [upload and download speed]

**Background** :
     We used to usually measure the internet speed by visiting sites like speedtest,broadband  etc, Its not effective since such websites contact **nearest isp** and provide the page download & upload speed which will vary based on server location

**Methods i tried and why its not effective**

1) Downloading a file from reputed site like microsoft,google drive etc which gives best download speed ,Limitation : Speed varies based on server perfomance and mirrors

2)Downloading a file from torrent sites which also has limitation based on leechers and peers

3)By sharing internet with hotspot which shows different speed while connecting wifi and clean ethernet.

Other than that DNS CACHE,Network CARD,ethernet makes the bandwidth speed vary.

So how can i test my real bandwidth speed?

myself is just a home connection with normal adsl modem,Any other effective ways to test my real internet speed?

Comment: downvoters pls explain why the downvote is for?usually downvote would be based on lack of research or its not useful

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish?  You have done several things that would give you your practical, working internet speeds.  The connection speed is **always** going to be limited by who you are connected to, so trying to measure *only* the speed "on your end" is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your real bandwidth is the bandwidth between you and your internet service provider. Download something big from your ISP's homepage - this is the most close.

But I think you haven't subscribed for dedicated max. bandwidth (which costs 2-3 times more), so you share one uplink with hundreds/thousands of users at the same time, so the bandwidth is changing dynamically.

Every ISP offers a minimal dedicated bandwidth to everyone, but it's ridiculously low value. (0 bytes/sec in extreme cases.)

If you wanna dedicated maximum bandwidth then pay more.